# Compile an old Linux kernel on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, linux-kernel

I tried to compile the Linux kernel 3.10.31 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
I used to compile the exact same kernel on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and everything works well.

On Ubuntu 16.04, the gcc version is `gcc-5`;
On Ubuntu 12.04, the gcc version is `gcc-4.6`.

It seems that the Linux kernel kernel before 3.18 cannot compile with the `gcc-5`. The kernel 3.10.31 reports the following error when it is compiled by `make`

```
 fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc5.h: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install gcc-4.7 onto Ubuntu 16.04 and change the `/usr/bin/gcc` to point to the gcc-4.7. This could solve the above error. However, it leads to new issues after I run `make`

```
$linux/arch/x86/Makefile:98: stack protector enabled but no compiler support
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'relocs'.
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
gcc-4.7.real: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-no-pie’
linux/./Kbuild:35: recipe for target 'kernel/bounds.s' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 1
Makefile:835: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

**My question is:**

Is there a neat way to use the old compiling chain to compile the old kernel 3.10.31 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Thank you very much for your help! Any advice is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured out a solution.

We don't have to install the old version gcc. We only need to copy the file compiler-gcc5.h [from here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx/master/include/linux/compiler-gcc5.h) or [from here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/siemens/u-boot/master/include/linux/compiler-gcc5.h) into include/linux/. It will solve the compilation issue.

Comment: that link is dead, however - here is another one:

[https://raw.githubusercontent.com/siemens/u-boot/master/include/linux/compiler-gcc5.h]

Comment: That link is dead.  Here's another one: [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/u-boot/u-boot/master/include/linux/compiler-gcc.h].

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 now still supports gcc-4.7 so you can install it and then you can choose the version of gcc before using it by `update-alternatives`.

For examples:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.4 40
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 50
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc # here you choose by hint
```

If you directly download `compiler-gcc5.h`, you may meet problems like `arch/x86/kvm/svm.c error invalid character` that I met when compiling `3.3.8` in Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Makefile, look for CFLAGS_EXTRA and add the following option to it -fno-pie.
See, https://askubuntu.com/questions/851433/kernel-doesnt-support-pic-mode-for-compiling.